# "first!" on AR CollectionProxy raises "undefined method [] for nil" after updating from Rails 4.1.4 to 4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm starting to upgrade from Rails 4.1.4 to Rails 4.2.0.  It looks like first! is no longer supported on some active record associations.

*What happened to `first!` (on ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy) to cause it to fail now?*

*How can fix the behavior so it works as in 4.1.4?*

Rails 4.1:

```
(byebug) user.organization.registration_codes
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<RegistrationCode id: 259, code: "AWESOMESAUCE" ... >]>

(byebug) user.organization.registration_codes.first!
#<RegistrationCode id: 259, code: "AWESOMESAUCE" ... >
```

Rails 4.2:

```
(byebug) user.organization.registration_codes
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<RegistrationCode id: 259, code: "AWESOMESAUCE" ... >]>

(byebug)  user.organization.registration_codes.first!
NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
nil
```

**Updated**

Digging into ActiveRecord, I find it failing here:

```
def find_nth(index, offset)
  if loaded?
    @records[index]
  else
    offset += index
    @offsets[offset] ||= find_nth_with_limit(offset, 1).first
  end
end
```

`loaded?` returns true, but @records is nil.  Throwing a debugger in and calling `find_nth_with_limit(offset, 1).first` returns the record that I expect.

`first!` is [defined in finder_methods.rb in active record](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a975407a0a4f8bb06f8d4696de6a8b5e5a086622/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L145) the issue seems to be that the association thinks its loaded, but @records is nil

Comment: first! doesn't appear to have been deprecated.

Comment: where is `first!` defined? AS I cannot find it in any documentation or source?

Comment: It is defined as part of active record finders  just doesn't appear to be defined on te collection proxy anymore.

Comment: It wasn't in 4.1 either, it must have been delegated to or copied over somewhere else in Rails. Either it's existence in the first place, or its removal is a bug :) Maybe jump onto the [Rails Core mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rubyonrails-core) and ask there.

Comment: It is in finder_methods.rb, line 145 or so in active record 4.2. The issue isn't that first! doesn't exist, rather that its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regression in Rails.  Calling one of the bang finder methods on a loaded collection in rails 4.2 does not work.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18237